# default(T) is null when T is a List

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following function:

```
public static T GetCachedBoxedValue<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getFromExternFunction, bool skipLocalCaches = false)
{
    var r = Manager.Get(
        cacheKey,
        () => new Tuple<T>(
            getFromExternFunction()
        ),
        skipLocalCaches
    );
    if (r == null || r.Item1 == null)
    {
        return default;
    }
    return r.Item1;
}
```

When T is a `List<Guid>` and the `r` value is null, it returns null.  How would I modify this to return a new empty list?

Comment: @TimSchmelter default is a shortcut for default(T)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the [new constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) to the method and call `new T()`:

```
public static T GetCachedBoxedValue<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getFromExternFunction, bool skipLocalCaches = false)
    where T:new()
{
    ...
    if (r == null || r.Item1 == null)
    {
        return new T();
    }
    return r.Item1;
}
```

The `new` constraint tells the debugger that only types that have a parameterless constructor can be used, allowing you to call it.

The `default` value for all reference types is `null`. An empty List on the other hand is a fully constructed List instance. For more information about default values see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe I mentioned that in the comments. That site isn't the best reference. Quite a lot of times, the articles have a surprising and annoying similarity to the doc pages or old blog posts. Plagiarism concerns aside, it's *really* annoying trying to find a solution to a burning problem and find out that the article you read is a mis-spelled copy of the doc page you already went through. Posting articles about eg SQL Server 2019 that still talk about the "recent SQL Server 2008" release is simply funny. Except the "copy"-writer used it as an MVP achievement.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, sorry I wrote my comment at the time when it wasn't contained in your post. Then let's add the official docs to the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values